# Graphic novel where the cover had a short blonde woman kissing a tanned man with mechanical parts coming out of his head

Tags: story-identification, comics

I first saw this graphic novel in the store called “Movie and trading co”. When I saw the cover for the first time, I wanted to give it a chance, but I didn’t have the money to pay for it back then. I forget about the book, till now I just remember the cover of the graphic novel, which had the following details:

- A man and a woman kissing
- The woman has short blonde hair, wears glasses, has a pink top.
- The background was white.
- The man has black hair, I think he has tan skin, wears an orange top, and there were mechanical parts coming out of his head floating to the left side of the cover.

I think it was published around 2010, but I'm **not** 100% sure of that.

Comment: Did you open the graphic novel? Do you remember any of the plot?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I only read the story premises one time. I don’t know the story plot. I think it have to do with the guy have an car accident that dramatic change his life.

Comment: I don’t think Dc, nor Marvel published the graphic novel.

Comment: I don’t think this help at all, but I remember the book being a hard cover.

Comment: Not to point out the obvious, but have you asked the staff/owner of the store where you saw it?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Answer (score 3):

I found it! The book I was looking for was “How to pass as human” (2015) by Nic Kelman.

[image: couple kissing, white background]

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25361629-how-to-pass-as-human):

> *How to Pass as Human* is an attempt on the part of the world's first android to understand the irrational, unpredictable, eclectic creatures known as human beings. Written in the form of a field guide, complete with sketches, graphs, flowcharts, and other reference materials, Android Zero (aka "Zach") has compiled a variety of useful information for future androids on how to pass undetected as human beings. Along the way, he also attempts to solve the mystery of his own creation with the help of Andrea, a human female who has taken an interest in him that may be more than friendly, and eventually leading him to "meet his maker" and discover the surprising purpose of his existence.

Comment: Good work! To merge your accounts so that you can click on the checkmark to accept, please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts